# Parse string to retrieve parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following string:

```
"paramFoo={12}, paramBar={1}, paramFooBar={2713}"
```

Now, I need to get the values for these 3 params. Is there any way to do that in JavaScript/jQuery and/or AngularJS?

I can only think of:

1. Search for 'paramFoo={' and remove it from the string.
2. Get position of first '}'
3. Get value from chars 0 - (pos from 2.)-1
4. Remove chars 0 - (pos from 2.) from string
5. [repeat 1-4 two more times]

Im sure, there must be a cleaner way to do that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: That doesn't look like standard ..... anything. You probably have to `split(',')` etc.

Comment: Yeah, split(",") is a good idea. But how can I get the value inside of {}? It is always a number from 0 too XXXX. split("{") and then split("}")?

Comment: **Do you need** to know that 12 is the value for paramFOO ?

Comment: And what did you tried so far?

Comment: Whats the data source? The cleanest way if you have control would be to send JSON and use `JSON.parse`. If you have to use that data format, maybe regex could be the answer. Split string on `,` then rip out word part and rip out numbers (if they're consistently of type Number). Let me know if you need help with the regex. But JSON is your safest bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
function parse(s) {
    var re = /^([a-zA-Z]+)=\{([0-9]+)\}(?:\,\s*(.*))?$/, parts, res = {};
    while (s && (parts = re.exec(s))) {
        res[parts[1]] = parseInt(parts[2]);
        s = parts[3];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Works just perfect (returns object with key=>value). Thank you very (!) much! <3

Comment: Updated it: I had forgotten to check that s is not null (it worked nonetheless on chrome.)

Answer (score 4):

Just use a regex!

```
str.match(/\d+/g)
```

will give you an array of `[12,1,2714]`.

If you have something other than numbers, the regex will be more complex.

Comment: where is the connection between 12 to paramFoo ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir OP only says he needs the values, not the name of the param it was assigned to.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I dont think the OP knows what he wants to tell you the truth. he's just not clear enough

Comment: @RoyiNamir That I agree with :)

Comment: That just extracts numbers, any numbers. It works here, but doesn't seem like a very good solution in the long run, but who knows, maybe it's all that's needed ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tested it, and it works like you described. The only problem is now, that (like royi saided) the key is missing, which is needed, since the order of the parameters could be different in very special cases.